# Saving The Location of Multiple Objects Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have multiple objects of the same class type, which are draggable. I want to save each of their location after dragging, so that when the page is reloaded, they are at the saved location.

Here is the code:

```
$(function(){

    var Pos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("position"));

    var currentPos = {
        top : 0,
        left : 0
    };

    var c = [];

    $('.framewrap').each(function(){
        id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(Pos[id].top);

        $(this).css({
            top : Pos[id].top,
            left : Pos[id].left
        });

        $(this).draggable({

            drag: function(event,ui){
                currentPos = $(this).position();
                c.push(currentPos);
                localStorage.setItem("position", JSON.stringify(c))
            }

        });

    });

});
```

The position gets saved, but the problem is that both the objects are assigned to the same position, rather than different. Looks like the position gets over-written each time.

Any one highlight what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: At first glance, I'm seeing that you get the localStorage item and assign it to a variable. But then you reassign that variable with "0,0".

Comment: Also check this, maybe it helps https://forum.jquery.com/topic/save-position-of-draggable-item

Comment: The above link is for a single object. I want to do that for multiple objects belonging to the same class !

Comment: What ids do these items have? You get the position from `localStorage` through the id but save it by `c.push(currentPos);`

Comment: The ids are 0 and 1